# making VLC play external stream using VB.net

Tags: vb.net, vlc

Hi I would like to programmatically make VLC play a video stream. I dont want to embed VLC just make it play. Normally I start VLC to play a local file like this

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("VLC.exe", link to local file)
```

when I try the same process but supplying a vid stream I get an error saying the file cant be found.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("VLC.exe", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y2C_3swE9sQ&list=PLrEnWoR732-BHrPp_Pm8_VleD68f9s14-&index=37")
```

It is supposed to be possible as per the instruction on VLC website:

To receive a HTTP stream, start VLC with : % vlc http://www.example.org/your_file.mpg  but I can't seam to get it done.

Could someone point me in the right dirrection?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfectly with `VLC 2.2.1` which is the latest version.

To avoid `The system cannot find the file specified` error is better specify complete path of executable:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe",
    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y2C_3swE9sQ&list=PLrEnWoR732-BHrPp_Pm8_VleD68f9s14-&index=37"
)
```

If you can't upgrade please note that this isn't a VB.NET problem but an incompatibility between new YouTube format and old versions of VLC: google `vlc youtube.lua fix` for a possible solution (not tested).

Comment: I have VLC 2.2.1 VS 2014 Update 5 and the program is for .Net4. Still cant get the program to execute. I get : An unhandled exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: maybe is better use complete path for `vlc.exe` (i.e.: `C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe`)